# Passing objects to other objects - via methods or constructor?

Tags: python, oop, class, theory

Here's the situation.  I have the following pseudo classes:

```
class Agent:
    def __init__(self):
       self.blah = whatever
       self.boo = thingy

    def doA(self, transport):
       res = transport.doX(self.blah)

    def doB(self, transport):
       res = transport.doY(self.boo)

class Transport:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bah = weee

    def doX(self, item):
        #.. do some other stuff here

    def doY(self, item):
        #.. do some more stuff here
```

Now, my question is - should I be passing my transport object into the Agent methods for the methods that require it or should I simply be passing the Transport object into the Agent constructor and calling it from within the methods? ie

```
transport = Transport()
agent = Agent(transport)
class Agent:
    def __init__(self, transport):
        self.blah = whatever
        self.transport = transport

    def doA(self):
        res = self.transport.doX(self.blah)
```

The reasons I moved Transport out to it's own class are:

1) The agent instances can share the same transport object - ie: I only need 1 transport object for a set of agents.  I can have multiple transports ( one for agentsA..N, another for agentsO..Z).

2) Transport contains methods that take a list of agents as an argument.  For example, it can run a concurrent communication test to the agents, given a list of agent objects.

But, the agent itself sometimes requires attributes that are set in the Transport ( location of SSL certs, etc ) for some of the methods that make sense to be in the Agent class ( restarting the agent remotely, etc ).

Should I take the methods that require a list of agents and move them to be class methods of Transport and then make an attribute in the Agent objects that contain the Transport instance?  Should I continue what I'm doing and just require that a Transport object be passed to certain Agent object methods? Should I refactor this all in some way that I'm not seeing?

Any helpful opinions would be most appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you have another layer of coupling to break.

Comment: 1) Would the same agent ever work with several different transports? 2) Can an agent do something useful before any transport is connected to it? 3) Can a transport do something useful before any agent is connected to it?

Comment: Ignacio, I agree - but I'm asking this because I'm not sure how to decouple them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're even considering adding a transport as an argument to agent's constructor, I assume one agent will never work with multiple transports.

I assume a transport instance can do something useful without any agent connected to it, and vice versa.

If my assumptions are right, I would propose this:

```
class System:
  def associate_transport_and_agent(transport, *agents):
    for agent in agents:
      transport.add_agents(*agents)
      agent.set_transport(transport)

class Transport:
  def __init__(self):
    self.bah = weee
    self.agents = set()
  def add_agents(self, *agents):
    self.agents.update(agents)
  def remove_agent(self, agent):
    self.agents.remove(agent)
  def doX(self, item):
    # ...


class Agent:
  def __init__(self):
    self.blah = whatever
    self.transport = None
  def set_transport(self, transport):
    if self.transport == transport:
      return
    if self.transport is not None:
      self.transport.remove_agent(self)
    self.transport = transport

  def doA(self):
    res = self.transport.doX(self.blah)
```

If you plan to delete objects, you might need to help garbage collector by using weak references from either Agent to Transport or in the other direction (or in fact, in both directions in your case, since you presumably contain a strong reference to them elsewhere).

EDIT:

Updated to reflect that agents may change their transports:

- changed list of agents to set of agents
- added Transport.remove_agent
- modified Agent.set_transport to check if one was already set before

Comment: The agent can only ever work with 1 transport, although that transport can be switched.  Since this is all actually just an API to a larger server/client architecture, I'd say no.  I have to use a transport to communicate to the agent to do anything useful.  The only reason I moved the transport out was because of the methods that were operating across several agents at the same time.  It really seemed to be the wrong idea to keep that sort of logic within the Agent ( ie - using a method in one agent to affect itself and other agents ). I'll try something like you posted above.

Answer (score 0):

Given that "The agent can only ever work with 1 transport, although that transport can be switched", I would recommend that you have an (optional) parameter to your `__init__` to set the transport, and have the agent's transport attribute be public. If you ever need to run code on assignment, create a property.